# Github Workflow: Appending a line to every language file found in a directory tree

Tags: bash, build, github-actions

In the old build process i was appending a line at the end of every language file inside all language folders via Gulp:

```
gulp.src('some/folder/language/**/*.ini')
        .pipe(footer('\nCONSTANT_A=\"Some Text\"'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dest/folder/language'))
```

That was working good. Now i'm moving the build process to Github and trying to do that with a bash call in which i'm not that good. So this is a Git Workflow Call:

```
  - name: Append Language Constants
    run: |
      for i in some/folder/language/**/*.ini
      do
        echo '"\nCONSTANT_A=\"Some Text\"' >> $i
      done
```

I guess the directory masking via `/**/*.ini` is not possible?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "directory *masking*" but bash does expand `**` like this. (Note that if `globstar` is not enabled, this won't work; it should be enabled by default. See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117826/bash-globstar-matching)

Comment: Just meant that it should find all files in `/bla/*.ini` and `/blu/*.ini` and so on. Therefore, `/**/*.ini` should do it, right?

Comment: Yes, that should work fine.